# Build angular libraries with cross dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript, build, jenkins-pipeline

We are trying to build a set of common libraries (lib1 and lib2) to share among different Angular applications.

We created a new Angular workspace and then generate said libraries using the angular-cli.

The libraries are built one at a time using a separate jenkins pipeline which runs the commands:

```
For lib1: ng build --configuration production --project lib1
For lib2: ng build --configuration production --project lib2
```

And then cd into the /dist folder and publishes the appropriate library to a private repo.

The problem arises when lib2 has a dependency from lib1.
In that case what happens is the following:

1. While developing, the dependency cannot be found unless we build lib1 beforehand and create a /dist folder
2. When publishing lib2 the build breaks because it cannot find the reference for lib1

The questions are:

1. How can we develop locally without having to build the base library beforehand
2. How do we build and then use lib2 in an application? Is there something we have to change in our workspace configuration?

I've put together a very quick POC to illustrate the workspace structure https://github.com/miconte/lib-imports, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways: `npm link` or `npm pack`

If you are actively developing on both libraries and jumping back and forth between them, I'd suggest you use `npm link`.

If you are actively developing on lib2 but not on lib1, build lib1 (it will create files in `dist` folder), run `npm pack` there to create a `.tgz` / tarball file. Add the tarball as a file/local dependency in your `package.json`. Run `npm i` to install the dependency and check it has been added to the `node_modules`. Now in lib2 use the modules/services/components of lib1 ensuring the import/reference links are absolute (`import xyz from '@org/lib1'`) and not relative (`import xyz from '../../lib1/mod'`)

You can check out the forked version: https://github.com/im-zeeshan/lib-imports/commit/1c3b7a0226ca36cf9e0a885d0474ccd56c9a9821

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. We are developing on both libraries at the same time. Our issue is that we cannot run the link from the jenkins pipeline and we would like to produce a lib2 which comes with the minimum lib1 version bundled inside.

Comment: @miconte did you find a solution for that?